# A property not initialized... yet it should be?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, initialization

I have a list containing folders, and I'm trying to get the count of the total number of files in these folders.

I manage to retrieve a ListItemCollection containing my folders. Then it starts being... picky.

`ctx` is my ClientContext, and `collection` my ListItemCollection.

```
function countFiles()
{
    var enumCollection = collection.getEnumerator();

    while(enumCollection.moveNext())
    {
        currentItem = enumCollection.get_current();

        var folder = currentItem.get_folder();

        if (folder === 'undefined')
            return;

        ctx.load(folder, 'ItemCount');
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function()
            {
                totalCount += folder.get_itemCount();
            }), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
    }
}
```

So it works... half of the time. If I have 6 items in my collection, I get 3 or 4 "The property or field 'ItemCount' has not been initialized" exceptions, and obviously my totalCount is wrong. I just can't seem to understand why, since the executeQueryAsync should not happen before the folder is actually loaded.

I'm very new to Javascript, so it may look horrid and be missing some essential code I didn't consider worthy of interest, feel free to ask if it is so.

Comment: You're running into a very common problem with asynchronous callbacks and JavaScript closures.

Comment: @Pointy there must be some workaround. I mean, I can't be the only guy willing to do something like that, right?

Comment: I agree; I'm not familiar with that `.createDelegate()` thing but I think I know what it does.

Comment: If that can make you feel better, I'm not familiar with any of this. I copied these from other .js files in my workplace, so they may or may not be horrible practice :)

Comment: It's easy enough to fix the problem I suspect you're having with that reference to "folder" inside the callback, but another complication is that you really have no way of knowing when the process of totalling up the item counts is finished. Those asynchronous callbacks will finish when they finish, and *eventually* the total will be correct. Dealing with that is more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing closure variables (like `folder` in this case) from an asynchronous callback is generally a big problem. Thankfully it's easy to fix:

```
function countFiles()
{
    function itemCounter(folder) {
        return function() { totalCount += folder.get_itemCount(); };
    }

    var enumCollection = collection.getEnumerator();

    while(enumCollection.moveNext())
    {
        var folder = enumCollection.getCurrent().get_folder();

        if (folder === undefined) // not a string!
            return;

        ctx.load(folder, 'ItemCount');
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(itemCounter(folder), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
    }
}
```

(You don't need that `.createDelegate()` call because the function doesn't need `this`.)

Now, after that, you face the problem of knowing when that counter has been finally updated. Those asynchronous callbacks will eventually finish, but when?  You could keep a separate counter, one for each query you start, and then decrement that in the callback. When it drops back to zero, then you'll know you're done.

Comment: Note that I'm not familiar at all with that collection API, so my assumptions about its behavior could be wrong. However, a function with "Async" in its name and success/failure callbacks is almost certainly asynchronous.

Comment: Eh, with SharePoint, you never know. About the counter, I actually already implement it, but didn't want to make the code too heavy. Now, I don't really understand the usefulness of the inner function, therefore what your solution brings to the table. (once again, me = JS beginner D:) Is that just for the sake of passing a reference so we don't use the actual `folder` variable, so it can close in peace?

Comment: @Kilazur right - without that extra intermediary function, that same "folder" variable would be **shared** by all the callbacks, and things would just not work right.

Answer (score 1):

Since `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` is an **async** function it is likely that the loop could be terminated before the first call to callback function completes, so the behavior of specified code could be unexpected.

Instead, i would recommend another and more clean approach for counting files (including files located under nested folders) using SharePoint JSOM.

### How to count the total number of files in List using JSOM

The following function allows to count the number of list items in List:

```
function getItemsCount(listTitle, complete){
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var items = list.getItems(createQuery());
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          complete(items.get_count());
      },
      function() {
         complete(-1);
      }   
    );

    function createQuery()
    {
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
        query.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">0</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
        return query;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
getItemsCount('Documents', function(itemsCount){
    console.log(String.format('Total files count in Documents library: {0}',itemsCount));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, as this will be good for educational purposes, but my issue is more about what Pointy... points out in his comments, than the actual fact of counting items.